# tvOS 10.2 pairing protocol

Tags: ios, tvos, airplay

Is it possible to find somewhere the protocol used to pair/authenticate a by `AirPlay` and that is mandatory on `tvOS` 10.2? A quick `Wireshark` of `iTunes` controlling an `AppleTV` gives a rough idea of what's happening but does not gives the format of what is exchanges.

Thanks

> POST /pair-pin-start RTSP/1.0 CSeq: 1 User-Agent: iTunes/12.6
>   (Windows; Microsoft Windows 7 x64 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1
>   (Build 7601); x64) Client-Instance: A2FAF33ECFE99167 DACP-ID:
>   A2FAF33ECFE99167 Active-Remote: 3742669230
>
> RTSP/1.0 200 OK Server: AirTunes/320.20 CSeq: 1
>
> POST /pair-setup-pin RTSP/1.0 CSeq: 2 Content-Type:
>   application/x-apple-binary-plist Content-Length: 86 User-Agent:
>   iTunes/12.6 (Windows; Microsoft Windows 7 x64 Ultimate Edition Service
>   Pack 1 (Build 7601); x64) Client-Instance: A2FAF33ECFE99167 DACP-ID:
>   A2FAF33ECFE99167 Active-Remote: 3742669230
>
> bplist00.....VmethodTuserSpin_..00:FF:E1:61:F9:87.
>   ..................................1
>
> RTSP/1.0 200 OK Content-Length: 342 Content-Type:
>   application/x-apple-binary-plist Server: AirTunes/320.20 CSeq: 2
>
> bplist00.....RpkTsaltO....c.Li.4...L.............~....%k#..P2.5...G.U..Y..R..{<...r..O....f#.|65ds....+....Nd..PtSp.g.....S..A..k..c.N...D.B$../....|..^.Y...J^I...h;..|6........H.H.8q8....L........]fw....k.....|..7B>....6.z....+.9Es.7(...8E...j.W....U...f..`.H...HE........onv>f.O......7.;&C..U.z@{...
>   .....................................,
>
> POST /pair-setup-pin RTSP/1.0 CSeq: 3 Content-Type:
>   application/x-apple-binary-plist Content-Length: 347 User-Agent:
>   iTunes/12.6 (Windows; Microsoft Windows 7 x64 Ultimate Edition Service
>   Pack 1 (Build 7601); x64) Client-Instance: A2FAF33ECFE99167 DACP-ID:
>   A2FAF33ECFE99167 Active-Remote: 3742669230
>
> bplist00.....RpkUproofO.....~.!..S|..5..M..)7..r.?.....j.N..0...[K.uu..
>   q+..O.0...c.!...\O......*.[k(.6.?Mv..-yS.......;k..n...@5....9.@.K.N..
>   .....
>   V.._k..........E.^}0.&...mvwpA=)X.}....OF...JZQ...o.,..(..G.g.{...0....wj,?...........G.m,.....   .0.)..S....7...1.Q9PA.ni.d=....<=..}.O..2....d......    ..Z..j....
>   .....................................1
>
> RTSP/1.0 200 OK Content-Length: 75 Content-Type:
>   application/x-apple-binary-plist Server: AirTunes/320.20 CSeq: 3
>
> bplist00...UproofO...G.f.)....A....q.P)...................................(POST
>   /pair-setup-pin RTSP/1.0 CSeq: 4 Content-Type:
>   application/x-apple-binary-plist Content-Length: 116 User-Agent:
>   iTunes/12.6 (Windows; Microsoft Windows 7 x64 Ultimate Edition Service
>   Pack 1 (Build 7601); x64) Client-Instance: A2FAF33ECFE99167 DACP-ID:
>   A2FAF33ECFE99167 Active-Remote: 3742669230
>
> bplist00.....SepkWauthTagO.
>   .p..^.......vLk.&....&.(A.].....O..K...sW.&#..Q.....
>   ..<...............................O
>
> RTSP/1.0 200 OK Content-Length: 116 Content-Type:
>   application/x-apple-binary-plist Server: AirTunes/320.20 CSeq: 4
>
> bplist00.....SepkWauthTagO. K.@O...E.&ED...Q
>
> POST /pair-verify RTSP/1.0 CSeq: 5 Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream Content-Length: 68 X-Apple-PD: 1 User-Agent:
>   iTunes/12.6 (Windows; Microsoft Windows 7 x64 Ultimate Edition Service
>   Pack 1 (Build 7601); x64) Client-Instance: A2FAF33ECFE99167 DACP-ID:
>   A2FAF33ECFE99167 Active-Remote: 3742669230
>
> .........?./.U..{..2.*'...bx).on.s.5...L.c.....{q..V^s?A4.P.mJ J...s
>
> RTSP/1.0 200 OK Content-Length: 96 Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream Server: AirTunes/320.20 CSeq: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple TV device verification has been reverse engineered.
Here is the link to the project https://github.com/funtax/AirPlayAuth.

Comment: Worked, thank you. I created a doc here:  https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/philippe44/RAOP-Player/blob/master/doc/auth_protocol.html

Comment: Hey there, I am the author of AirPlayAuth. With tvOS13 this seems to be broken. If anyone can help, please feel free to create a ticket :)